# Insert into google calendar API v3 puts time 1 hour ahead

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I am inserting the following date into a google calendar: `2018-05-10T09:00:00.000Z`. This works fine however it shows the date at 10am instead of 9am.

The date is formatted as UTC. I have tried putting the timezone and even the 'Reykjavik' trick.

```
let calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  let auth = generateOAuth(cal)
  let insert = {
    "end": {
      "dateTime": booking.endDate.toISOString(),
  "timeZone": 'Europe/London' //NOTE We use Atlantic/Reykjavik to allow us to set UTC times in GOOGLE CALENDAR. https://blog.gerv.net/2012/11/the-rekjavik-trick/
    },
    "start": {
      "dateTime": booking.date.toISOString(),
  "timeZone": 'Europe/London' //NOTE We use Atlantic/Reykjavik to allow us to set UTC times in GOOGLE CALENDAR. https://blog.gerv.net/2012/11/the-rekjavik-trick/
    },
    "description": booking.service.name,
    "summary": `${booking.booker.fname} ${booking.booker.lname}`,
    "extendedProperties": {
      "private": {
        "bookingId": booking.date._id
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By doing a [cleandar.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get)  on the caledar you are inserting into you will see something like this

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"mHn5bZBLmCgV5zrOjYDUo0wE/WK1K2C9CsAxePbI13h8-KuIOLek\"",
 "id": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "eventHangout"
  ]
 }
}
```

Note the timezone on the calendar itself.  If you insert an event to a time zone that is different then the time zone of the calendar then when you view the event the time will be corrected to that of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

@DalmTo pointed me in the right direction. To fix the issue I had to recreate my date object from UTC to the correct timezone.

I used [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to do this.

```
  let utcDate = moment.utc(booking.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
  let timezone = business.regionality ? business.regionality.timezone : 'Europe/London'
  let reformattedDate = mtz.tz(utcDate, timezone).toISOString()
```